# Conway's Game of Life Python All Cells Die On First Iteration

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I'm a beginner to python and I'm trying to program the Game of Life as practice for a class. I'm trying to debug the code at this point, and I've encountered a problem where all cells display as being dead on the first iteration, regardless of the starting layout.

Example run:

**Starting Board:**

```
00000
00000
000X0
000X0
000X0
```

**Iteration  1:**

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

I suspect the problem lies in one of 2 functions.
Here's the code that calls on the `nextIteration` function I made:

```
numIters = int(input("How many iterations should I run?: "))

print("Starting Board:")
printBoard(myBoard)
for t in range(1,numIters+1):
    myBoard = nextIteration(myBoard)
    print("Iteration ",t,":")
    printBoard(myBoard)
```

Here's the `nextIteration` function:

```
def nextIteration(board):
    board2 = board
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for v in range(len(board[0])):
            myNum = numAlive(i,v,board)
            if(board[i][v] == "X"):
                if(myNum < 2):
                    board2[i][v] = 0
                elif(myNum > 3):
                    board2[i][v] = 0
            elif(board[i][v] == 0):
                if(myNum == 3):
                    board2[i][v] = "X"

    return board2
```

Here's the function I'm using to count living neighbors (AKA `numAlive`):

```
def numAlive(row,col,board):
    count = 0
    #Row exits above cell
    if(row != 0):
        if(board[row-1][col] == "X"):
            count = count + 1
        #Column exists to left of cell
        if(col != 0):
            if(board[row-1][col-1] == "X"):
                count = count + 1
        #Column exists to right of cell
        if(col != (len(board[0])-1)):
            if(board[row-1][col+1] == "X"):
                count = count + 1
    #Row exists below cell
    if(row != (len(board)-1)):
        if(board[row+1][col] == "X"):
            count = count + 1
        #Column exists to left of cell
        if(col != 0):
            if(board[row+1][col-1] == "X"):
                count = count + 1
        #Column exists to right of cell
        if(col != (len(board[0])-1)):
            if(board[row+1][col+1] == "X"):
                count = count + 1

    #Column exists to left of cell
    if(col != 0):
        if(board[row][col-1] == "X"):
            count = count + 1
    #Column exists to right of cell
    if(col != (len(board[0])-1)):
        if(board[row][col+1] == "X"):
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

I've rewritten this a few times now to no effect. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: change board2 = board to board2 = deepcopy(board). just assigning one array to another doesn't make a copy. you might also need: from copy import copy, deepcopy